# Async side effect depends on another effect

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have two side effects. One of them presents a global loading spinner and the other one dismisses the spinner again. For presenting and dismissing the loader I have created a LoadingService. Note that the `presentLoader()` and `dismissLoader()` methods are async. Reason is that the service encapsulates the `LoadingController` of the Ionic framework.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingService {

  private loader?: HTMLIonLoadingElement;

  constructor(private loadingController: LoadingController) {
  }

  public async presentLoader(translationKey: string): Promise<void> {
    if (this.loader) {
      this.loader.message = translationKey;
      return;
    }
    this.loader = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: translationKey
    });
    await this.loader.present();
  }

  public async dismissLoader(): Promise<void> {
    await this.loader?.dismiss();
    this.loader = undefined;
  }
}
```

In my Application i work with the RequestStarted, RequestSucceeded and RequestFailed Action naming pattern.

```
public updateMyThingsItem$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(
      MyThingsItemActions.updateMyThingsItemNameRequested,
      MyThingsItemActions.updateMyThingsItemPurchasePriceRequested,
      MyThingsItemActions.updateMyThingsItemPurchaseDateRequested
    ),
    exhaustMap((action) =>
      this.myThingsIntegrationService.patchMyThingsItem(action.myThingsItem.id, action.myThingsItem.changes).pipe(
        map((myThingsItem) => MyThingsItemActions.updateMyThingsItemSucceeded({ myThingsItem })),
        catchError((error: string) => of(MyThingsItemActions.updateMyThingsItemFailed({ error })))
      )
    )
  );
});
```

Now I created a side effect to display a loader for a couple of RequestStarted actions and a side effect that hides the loader again for the related Succeeded and Failed actions. This looks something like this:

```
public presentLoadingSpinner$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(
      MyThingsItemActions.updateMyThingsItemNameRequested,
      MyThingsItemActions.updateMyThingsItemPurchasePriceRequested,
      MyThingsItemActions.updateMyThingsItemPurchaseDateRequested
    ),
    exhaustMap(() => this.loadingService.presentLoader('loading...'))
  );
}, {
  dispatch: false
});

public hideLoadingSpinner$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(
      MyThingsItemActions.updateMyThingsItemSucceeded,
      MyThingsItemActions.updateMyThingsItemFailed
    ),
    exhaustMap(() => this.loadingService.dismissLoader())
  );
}, {
  dispatch: false
});
```

Now for my problem: Because the methods in my loadingService are async there is the possibility that the side effect to dismiss the loader is triggered before the `presentLoader()` method is completed and the loader does not yet exist in the DOM. This happens when the API is really quick or a client error (no network) happens and the Failure Action is dispatched before the loader is created.

I therefore realise that I now have depending effects. But how else could I solve the problem with a side effect that triggers async code?

I know that I could create a loading state with a `isLoading` flag. But I would have the same problem when creating the effect from a selector.

An other possibility would be to create an overlaying Loader Component in the AppComponent that is rendered on the `isLoading` flag. But then I would have to give up the `LoadingController` of the Ionic framework which I do not really like.

I would like to know how to solve these problems in general when calling a side effect method that is async.

Comment: Is that something that maybe my `LoadingService` should solve instead? Meaning that the `LoadingService` is stateful and I should wait for the existence of a LoadingElement before dismissing?